# Добавление .py файла в автозагрузку debian 12

Tags: python, debian

У меня есть файл **/Some_folder/main.py**, как мне сделать так что бы он автоматически запускался при загрузке ос. Пробовал через rc.local что что-то пошло не так. Буду благодарен за предоставленную информацию.

Answer (score 0):

Завернуть в баш ваш скрипт  script.sh
cd /Some_folder/ && python(ваша версия)main.py

Далее заворачиваем сервис
в sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/script.service

```
[Unit]
Description=описание
[Service]
ExecStart= путь до скрипта /script.sh
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

и далее службу тыкаем

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable script.service
sudo systemctl start script.service
sudo systemctl status script.service
```